# Why is the function not invoked in content of Modal window?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, modal-dialog

I am using kendo to make a responsive modal window with angular 1.

This is my main html file:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">

<button data-ng-click="showPopUp()">My Button</button>



        <div id="dialog">
        </div>

    <script>
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
    visible: false,
    actions: ["Close"],
    draggable: true,
    height: "20%",
    modal: true,
    pinned: true,
    position: {
        top: 200,
        left: 200
    },
    resizable: false,
    title: "Modal Window",
    width: "50%",
    content: "file:///C:/Users/adish/Desktop/New folder/passwordChangeWindow.html"
});

angular.module("myModule",[]);

angular.module("myModule").controller("myController",myController);

function myController($scope){

$scope.showPopUp = function(){

        var dialog = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
        dialog.open();
}

$scope.changeUserPassowrd = function(){
alert("function called");
}       
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And below is the html file containing the content of the modal window:

```
div>
<button class="k-button ok-button" data-ng-click="changeUserPassowrd(curPass,newPass,confirmPass,'na')">Ok</button>
</div>
```

But when I click the ok button in the modal window, the function in the controller is not invoked.

It was working for me with this syntax as below:

```
<div kendo-window="win2" k-title="helpTitle"
         k-width="600" k-height="200" k-visible="false"
         k-content="..."
         k-on-open="win2visible = true" k-on-close="win2visible = false"></div>
  </div>
```

but I was not able to give height and width in percent in this. Please guide me on this issue.

Comment: any error caught in console

Comment: ideally if you got `var dialog = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
        dialog.open();` the instance in console then it suppose to work but if not work then use `$scope.$apply()` then also not work then try to use `$compile('html')($scope)`

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205046/using-a-modal-window-with-kendoui-inside-of-angularjs]

Comment: @Jayant Patil, Where can I write $scope.$apply()

Comment: if you are sure that function get called but modal is not open is that case use before `dialog.open();' this line otherwise use inline kendo attributes than using jquery go with angular way

Comment: please refer thsese links
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/angular
http://plnkr.co/edit/WY0x1n6PwIKqxK0sKr3u?p=preview